# MFC WebBrowser.Navigate error "A null reference pointer was passed to the stub."

Tags: c++, mfc, activex, webbrowser-control

In an c++ MFC Application, I have a WebBrowser embedded in the form.  It was imbedded in the form via the "Insert ActiveX Control..." dialog and then I created the IDispatch wrapper class and added a variable.

These are the instructions I was following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046(v=vs.85).aspx

After a few times of the dialog being created and destroyed, I am receiving a the error "A null reference pointer was passed to the stub." when I call the following:

```
m_browser->Navigate( _T("about:blank"), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
```

Unfortunately, I can't recreate this and niether can my QA department (just the clients supposedly Win 7 x64, being called from a win32 application).

Is there something wrong with this approach or am I missing something altogether?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) string instead of the literal `_T("about:blank")` and pass an empty variant instead of NULL:

```
COleVariant vUrl(_T("about:blank"));
COleVariant vEmpty;
m_browser->Navigate(V_BSTR(&vUrl), &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty);
```

That matches the signature of [IWebBrowser2::Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method:

```
HRESULT Navigate(
    BSTR url,
    VARIANT *Flags,
    VARIANT *TargetFrameName,
    VARIANT *PostData,
    VARIANT *Headers
);
```

Comment: Using COleVariant for the URL instead of a BSTR or literal didn't seem necessary, but passing in the empty variant instead of NULL seemed to fix the problem.

I find it odd that the Microsoft example uses NULLs and this was causing the problem.

Comment: You still should be using a `BSTR`, not a literal. `BSTRs` have a bit different memory storage layout than regular null-terminated strings, they store the length too. If an API has a `BSTR` in its signature, you should give it a properly allocated `BSTR`. I only used `COleVariant` for this because I don't know a better way in MFC to allocate a `BSTR` and wrap it with a smart pointer at once. In ATL, that would be `CComBSTR(L"about:blank")`.

Comment: I disagree with the need change the constant.  BSTR is strongly typed.  If the compiler wasn't able to convert between _T and BSTR it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Unfortunately, `BSTR` is not strongly typed. This is how it's defined in WTypes.h: `typedef /* [wire_marshal] */ OLECHAR *BSTR;`. And `OLECHAR` is an alias for `WCHAR`: `typedef WCHAR OLECHAR`. Thus, `BSTR` and `LPWSTR` are the same thing.